# Cloud foundry tenants - what?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

I reads some docs on cloud foundry and I didnt find the term **tenants** ,
my question is if Org is a tenants in cloud foundry term? if not what is the equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done that way.  You could setup your CF install such that one Org is one tenant.  Orgs are scoped such that resources in the org are isolated and not visible unless you're a part of that org.

It's not strictly required to have one org to one tenant.  Orgs & spaces are just ways to group and limit access to applications and services on CF.  You can use them in a number of different ways.  For example, you could have development & production orgs for the same tenant.

In my experience, it's more common to see each tenant (company, organization in company, billing unit, etc..) as the org and then spaces used to subdivide the org though.  For example, dev & prod spaces.

When contemplating your choices here, I would suggest that you look at the breakdown of org & space roles.  If you understand what roles are present and how those can be used to control access, then you'll be able to make the best decisions about how to use orgs & spaces in your environment.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/roles.html#roles

Comment: Thanks Daniel , one more question :), when creating user provided service you are able for example to add you own DB etc ,for this you should use the command like cf create-user-provided-service my-db-mine -p '{"username":"admin","password":"pa55woRD"}' , my question is how to I where and how should I put the implementation of my-db-mine?

Comment: That's not really related to the original question here.  Short answer is that user provided service should contain everything your app needs to locate the service.  User, pass, host, port, url, whatever is necessary.  That means the actual server the user provided service refers to can reside anywhere that is accessible to the application.  Your corp network, public cloud, VPS, public service provider, etc.  If you need more help, make a new question.

Comment: Done :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138011/user-provided-service-in-cloud-foundry , please see if you can help here either .Thanks sir.

Comment: One more question there is scenario  the tenant can contains two orgs or more ?