# Cloud foundry tenants vs org vs orgs

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I finding myself very hard to understand what is the concept of tenants in CF, is it org or can be several of orgs connected together and if so how the resource are shared between. 
can someone give simple example what and how CF support the multi-tenant environment .

this not help(me) too much ...
[Cloud foundry tenants - what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101095/cloud-foundry-tenants-what)

Comment: What is a tenant to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what can really be added beyond what's already been stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101095/cloud-foundry-tenants-what).  I'll try though.

In CF an org is the basic component that allows you to have multiple "tenants".  One org is completely separated from another org and one org cannot see or access resources in another org.  Each org also has the ability to contain multiple spaces.  A space provides the ability to further subdivide resources and limit access to resources within the space.

The concepts are intentionally opaque as that allows you to be a bit more flexible in their usage.  If a concrete example might help to explain things better, you could think of a CF org as a company and a space as a division or team within that company.  It's definitely not limited to that analogy though, just trying to provide a more concrete example of one way this could work.

Hope that helps!